# Deal with refresh token in React

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I need to use refresh-token to get new access-token and it expires. In frontend, when searching around I come across with 2 approaches:

1. Use axios interceptors to check if access-token is still valid or not => If it is not valid access-token (not expires), then use refresh-token to get a new access-token => If get new token success => perform the request.
2. Perform the request => server check access-token => if invalid then send error code to client => client then perform request to get new access-token => if get new token success => retry the request

I dont know which way is better. It seems to me that approach 1 is easier but it is may not the responsibility of client to check if access-token is valid or not. The second way seems good to me but how I retry the request after receiving new access-token

Answer (score 0):

I use other variant with assumption that each request to the backend is reseting the token expiriation datetime. In this case I have flow:

- login request => response with token and information how long `token` is valid (in seconds, for example key `expire_in_seconds`)
- on frontend side start counting down from `expire_in_seconds` to 0
- each authorized request to backend => reset on frontend side expiration time to `expire_in_seconds` (and on backend side too of course)
- when user is doing nothing for a while and counter is decreasing you can show message for user 'Your session will expire after {counter} seconds. **Keep the session**'
- if user will click button (**Keep the session**) - reset counter on both sides (backend and frontend)
- if user will not click the button - logout him

Comment: For me it's not best practice to do that way. Let's say my token expiration time is a day so it's waste of requests to renew it everytime

Comment: @coinhndp hmm, I have read again your post and actually my description is not covering your second variation. Is a third variation which we are using in bank application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:
Axios has error.config, this is last request, which catched with error.

```
    api.interceptors.response.use(
      response => {
       ...
      },
      error => {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          refreshToken(YOUR_DATA) // your method to refresh Token
          axios.request(error.config).then(response => { // makes the last request that passed with an error
           ...
           })
           .catch(error => console.log(error) 
         }
    ...
      }
    );
```